# Select excel data by condition?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a excel table, that I want to select column `A` data with a condition.But my formula not working.

```py
#pseudo code

column_A_idx
if column_A_idx % 5 == 1:
    get_B_column_data, put data At column G
```

So I write a excel formula `=IF(MOD(A1:A36, 5) = 1,B1:B36,0)`, That I want get column `A` data that meet `colun_A%5 == 1` condtion, and then get column "B" data put it some-where.

[image]

**The final result like this**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this function:

`=FILTER(A1:B36,MOD(A1:A36,5)=1,0)`

It filters the range based on the mod of column 'A's value.

The result is the filtered range, i.e. your expected result.

Comment: My excel no  this `FILTER`  formula.